# Hp Elitebook 8470p won't boot, caps lock blinks 3 times

Tags: laptop, memory, hardware-failure, hp-elitebook

So my laptop hasn't been working for the past few days and every time I go to turn it on all the lights (wireless button, power button, mute button, etc.) work and I can hear the fan working but the screen is completely black and the caps lock and num lock blink 3 times. I read online that the three blinks mean that the RAM needs to be reseated. I reseated the RAM as well as switched it with a working RAM but my computer still is not booting up. Is there anything I can do to fix my computer quickly on my own? I have to leave very soon for a trip and would like to bring my laptop with me.

Comment: What is the existing memory configuration?

Answer (score 1):

3 beeps is a memory error according to HP, see chart below

[image]

http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01732674#AbT2